# Vue property not valid with underscore

Tags: properties, vuejs2

I was doing some tests and I noticed that my properties are not valid when I used underscore.

Example:

```
new Vue({
el : "#form",

data: {
    errors: [],
    _username: '',
    _password: ''
});
```

on html file:

```
<input class="uk-input" type="text" v-model="_username" >
<input class="uk-input" type="password" v-model="_password">
```

With the code above the app won't render. If I remove the underscore it will work, does someone knows why this happens?

Comment: JSFiddle example here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/9bzxuecj/

Comment: I would not call them "property" but variable. As a property of object, it works well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer may be found in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data)

> Properties that start with `_` or `$` will **not** be proxied on the Vue instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and API methods. You will have to access them as `vm.$data._property`

In your templates, you will have to reference `$data._username` / `$data._password`, eg

```
<input class="uk-input" type="text" v-model="$data._username" >
<input class="uk-input" type="password" v-model="$data._password">
```

Demo here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/9bzxuecj/2/

Comment: Looks like I need to keep reading the docs. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: TBF reserving a common language pattern for your libraries internal use is an eyebrow raiser, and not something that most devs would expect to run into in a non-trivial framework...

Comment: There has been a discussion about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270709/vue-property-not-valid-with-underscore It's not gonna change anytime soon and it's kind of an issue TBH